# Web Application and its Copyrights classification

Tags: copyright, internet

I wanted to know the facts behind the Web Application Hosting and its classification respective to copyrights. I know the streaming of `Video` / `Audio` over Internet its comes under **OTT** (*over-the-top*) i.e., Internet Broadcasting.

I wanted to know the Website (*Static/Dynamic web application*) Hosting and consuming its comes under the **broadcast or Internet Broadcast or from which classification**? especially in India and European countries.

No where was it clearly defined.

Comment: Please clarify what's the country where the company is registered and the primary countries of your audience, since the law varies by country.

Comment: @Martheen - I modified my question.

Comment: how does indian *copyright* law refer to the *indian constititon*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[united-states](/questions/tagged/united-states)

in US copyright law, there are no "classifications" of copyright. A protected work is a protected work. There are a few special provisions for architectural and sculptural works, and quite a few for musical works, but different types of web transmission or hosting make no difference with regard to US copyright law. I don't know what difference such classifications might make in the law of India.

Comment: In Europe, some dynamically generated content might not fall under copyright because it was not created by a creator. Remember the flap about the rights when a monkey took a selfie with a human's camera? There are other protections for dynamic sites, however, and parts may fall under copyright.